# Q: error mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysql

This piece of code is giving me the same error over and over:

```
<center>
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM studenten");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>first name</th>
<th>last name</th>
<th>studentnummer</th>
</tr>";
```

The error is:

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Can someone help me please?

Comment: whee is your full code?it sates that `$link` which is must be a database connection object and actually that is not happening.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath Why should you need to stop with using the mysqli_* functions?

Comment: PUT YOUR FULL CODE PLEASE?

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath Your reading skills aren't that great than, the documents of the mysql_* functions will be removed, the functions will stay. mysqli_* functions are still getting updated like PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$link` is not a MySQLi connection link. Check it with `var_dump`:

```
die(var_dump($link));
```

Maybe you use it in function context and it is not global or something like this. For making the connection, you should use:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
```

Answer (score -1):

$link has to have a value, you need to open a connection with mysqli_connect or the objective version (new mysqli())

Here is how to do it:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Thanx, finally no more errors :D

Comment: @ldruenen Graag gedaan ;) / Your welcome :p